# Difference between using "changed" and "did change" in this sentence

Tags: questions

Which one is the correct way of asking this question? When?

a) Why you changed your job?

b) Why did you change your Job?

c) Let me know why you changed your job?

d) Let me know why did you change your job?

Comment: Neither sentence is grammatical. a) *Why* ***have*** *you changed your job?* b) *Why did you change* ***your job***? Assuming those corrections, both sentences are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) Why you changed your job?

This is grammatically incorrect because if you want to ask in the past, you use 'did' for this case.

> b) Why did you change your Job?

This one is correct.

> c) Let me know why you changed your job?

This is not a question so question mark(?) makes it incorrect.

> d) Let me know why did you change your job?

This one is also incorrect. If you want to express something like this, you use the previous sentence but without the question mark(?).

Answer (score 2):

First form is not grammatically correct. The interrogative form has the following structure:

> auxiliary verb + subject + verb

In the case of past tense, the interrogative form is:

> did + subject + infinitive without *to*

Thus, the 2nd form is grammaticaly correct:

Why *did* **(aux vb)** *you* **(subject)** *change* **(vb)** your job?

Comment: I have edited the question